# How to enable HttpOnly cookies on ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web site

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a standard ASP.NET Core MVC website with Core 2.1 in Visual Studio using File->New Project.

In the Startup.cs is the boilerplate code

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

When I browse the site there is a single .AspNet.Consent cookie when I accept the cookiepolicy. It is marked by default secure but not httponly.

How to I enable HttpOnly on ALL cookies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consent cookie is not HttpOnly because it is set client side via JavaScript. You can find the code in the `_CookieConsentPartial.cshtml`:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var button = document.querySelector("#cookieConsent button[data-cookie-string]");
        button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            document.cookie = button.dataset.cookieString;
        }, false);
    })();
</script>
```

If you need an HttpOnly cookie you should implement the consent logic yourself in middleware or a controller and use a regular form with a POST-request for example.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. It seems the only way is to hook into Microsofts cookie middleware and set HttpOnly on their cookies there.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this?

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

});
```

Comment: This is not the best answer for the question asked, but it is the best for solving the specific issue with the 'consent' cookie, as is recently occurring with Chrome 80.

Comment: Is it possible create aspnet core  non persistent cookie?

Comment: @Grim I'm sorry; what is the best answer in general?

Comment: @ruffin Shamefully, I can't remember!  I don't do much web coding any more; I've given it some thought and can't reason why I said it wasn't the best answer at the time!  I suggest the accepted answer, although it sounds like a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 1):

When setting a cookie manually (e.g. against an HTTPContext), there is an easy CookieOptions object that you can use to set HttpOnly to true. It ends up looking a bit like this :

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
"CookieKey",
"CookieValue",
new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = true
});
```

Microsoft have a middleware that uses cookies for Authentication. If you were to use it in your app, you add it in the Configure method of your startup.cs.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseCookieAuthentication();
}
```

If you are using CookieAuthentication in this way, [HttpOnly cookies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.cookiehttponly?view=aspnetcore-2.2) will be used by default. For more details,refer to [here](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/15/httponly-cookies-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks, I've read that site but could not get any of the suggestions to work.

Comment: ```CookieAuthenticationOptions``` is obsoloted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you can do this in Startup.cs using the IApplicationBuilder.UseCookePolicy:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
       ...
     
        app.UseCookiePolicy(
            new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                Secure = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
                HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.Always
            });
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookiepolicyoptions.httponly?view=aspnetcore-2.1